# Retrieving the values in an un - ordered list and list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html rendered in the format below.
I want to be able to get the values 13,14,15 and store in different variables.
I want to be able to get the value id=9 as well for this row.
I will be updating a table and needs this Id together with the other rows.

Here is the html rendered

```
        <li class="main">
          <ul class="sub">
             <li id="9">
                <div class="innera">13</div>
                <div class="innerb">14</div>
                <div class="innerc">15</div>
                <div class="innerpencil">
                    <img class="modify" src="/images/icon-pencil" />
                </div>
             </li>
          </ul>
        <li>
```

Here is the jquery I am trying to write

```
        $(document).on("click", "img.modify", function () {
            var rowA = $("ul[class='sub'] li[div.class innera]")
            var rowB = $("ul[class='sub'] li[div.class innerb]")
            var rowB = $("ul[class='sub'] li[div.class innerc]")
            var Id of row ?
        });
```

Right now I am not getting anything for the variables? Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to review the jQuery (CSS) selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

`$("ul[class='sub'] li[div.class innera]")` won't match anything.

`$('ul.sub>li>div.innera')` would work, but maybe you want something a little different. Take a look at the selectors docs, and some trial and error :)

Comment: Yes it does: https://jsfiddle.net/ycwaswjh/ Maybe you should clarify what you are trying to do

Comment: @user2320476 — "It doesn't work" ... _**What** doesn't work?_ What did you actually try based on this answer? "It doesn't work" is not in any way helpful to the person that is trying to help you. And, to be completely clear, you don't use the word `class` when writing a selector to get a class

Comment: Thanks dan08. I see its working on your jsfiddle. There might be some other things going on with my page. I will look at it closely.  Some people are just very rude on this site.

Comment: @dan08 - This is all I got back [prevObject:init[1], context:document,selector:"ul.sub>li>div.innera"]

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a foreach loop on the li tag?

Like this?

```
   $(document).on("click", "img.modify", function () {
        var id = $('.sub > li').first().attr("id");
        console.log(id);

        $('#'+id+' > .divValue').each(function () {
            var variableName = $(this).text();
            console.log(variableName);


        });

    });

    }
```

I would add an class to the elements value you want.

Like this:

```
 <li class="main">
          <ul class="sub">
             <li id="9">
                <div class="innera divValue">13</div>
                <div class="innerb divValue">14</div>
                <div class="innerc divValue">15</div>
                <div class="innerpencil">
                    <img class="modify" src="/images/icon-pencil" />
                </div>
             </li>
          </ul>
        <li>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this too and get back to you.